# Fading in with JS, on body css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I fade in this new background image every 10 seconds? I want it to take around 3 seconds to fade in, every 10 seconds it changes.

I've looked all over google but nothing actually shows how to do it with body.

```
var x = -1, backgroundImages = [
    "/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg",
    "/images/background-gmail-google-images_FG2XwaO.jpg",
    "/images/beautiful-sunset-images-196063.jpg"
];

function changeImage() {
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 10000);
}

function displayNextImage() {
    x = (x === backgroundImages.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + backgroundImages[x] + "')";
}
```

Comment: Where do you trigger your `changeImage()`

Comment: onload of the body element.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about changing images with JS, then your code should work (given that the changeImage function is called), but if this question is about fading in-out, then you should use CSS animations. You can wrap your images in a div and play with it's opacity, since the backgroundImage property doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS transition, in a class an work with background and opacity..like the example

```js
var x = -1, backgroundImages = [
    "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "http://via.placeholder.com/350x151",
    "http://via.placeholder.com/350x152"
];

function changeImage() {
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 10000);
}

function displayNextImage() {
    x = (x === backgroundImages.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
    document.body.classList.remove('fade-image');
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + backgroundImages[x] + "')";
    document.body.classList.add('fade-image');
}
//first time
displayNextImage();
// set Interval
changeImage();
```

```css
body{
opacity:0;

-webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;

}
.fade-image{
opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [time interval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) that triggers the `changeImage()` function:

```
var x = -1, t, backgroundImages = [
"/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg",
"/images/background-gmail-google-images_FG2XwaO.jpg",
"/images/beautiful-sunset-images-196063.jpg"
];

function changeImage() {
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 10000);
}

function displayNextImage() {
    x = (x === backgroundImages.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + backgroundImages[x] + "')";
}

t = setInterval(changeImage, 10000);
```

To give it the effect of fade in and out, create a div with a `zindex` that put it behind all other elements (also `position: absolute;`), make it a 100% width and height and apply the image on it...

Answer (score 0):

background images *cannot* be faded in or out - that's a process that would involve applying opacity *only* to the background image, which doesn't exist. It's only possible to fade a complete element (for example a regular `img` tag), but not to the `background-image` of an element.